# sending user verification code through facebook

Tags: php

I am making a user registration / login system in php and want to verify the user by sending him/her a verification code that the user has to type to make an account .

Now i dont want to send the verification code through mail( phpmail / phpmailer) or any sms service, instead i want to send the code to his facebook messages inbox from my facebook account by using his email id..is it possible to do so? is there any method or api that allows such type of function?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

This [website](http://content.api.ai/facebook-messenger-bot) provides a powerful api that will do just what you need.
You can also check the [Facebook doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference)